# unpacking data, using struct.unpack(format, data),without knowing the format of it

Tags: python, network-programming

Here is my problem :
(This code is written in python)

I have information being streamed from a proxy to a port.  This uses UDP.  So in python, I am listening to that port and putting the information into a variable "data".  I now want to unpack this data using the struct.unpack(format, data) method.  Here is the problem, I don't know the format of this incoming data.  Is there any way to generate a format string that I can use for this method by looking at the bits coming in (the current bits held in the "data" variable)? At the very least, I know for certain inside the data will be protobuf files, and a float.

Is this even possible? To unpack without knowing the format before hand?

Here is some code (very simple bind to port collect data):

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("", port))
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
#I don't know what to put here : 
unpacked_data = struct.unpack("????", data)
```

Much appreciated,
-Michael

Comment: While not necessary, I think you would be better served by actually showing your current implementation to give people something to really work off of.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code you've tried?